# Ionic 2 , blank project takes 15 secs to load the main page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I create ionic 2 project the following command:

```
ionic start myNewIonicApp blank --v2
```

then I checked the plugins for my curiosity using the command,

```
ionic plugin list
```

here is the result that I got

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Then I added the android platform and run it

```
ionic platform add android
ionic run android --prod
```

I saw the white blank page between splash screen and main page and It takes 15 sec. I didn't modify anything and just build and run. so I added the two line in config.xml file.

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

After building and run the application, there is no white blank screen. Although I saw only splash screen and main page, It still take 15 sec. How can I do it faster? I didnt modify anything (just build and run).

Comment: Please check this [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-speed-up-boot-time/46372/133)

Comment: I upgraded to RC5 and change/copy some code in **config.xml** from an official ionic app and the problem seems solved without any tricks and now load correctly and fast. If you need more details, I can add a reply with infos.

Comment: Hi mosca, pls give me infos or some links. Thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

I've never built for Android but I believe its the same process. You have to build for production/release:

```
$ ionic build --release --prod ios ('android' in your case)
```